# PGP Command - Eyes Only

Tags: pgp

I tried to use the following command to redirect PGP output from command prompt:

```
pgp --decrypt fileA.pgp --passphrase 'pp123' --eyes-only > std.txt 2> err.txt
```

What I can get is:

```
std.txt: 
NOTHING

err.txt: 
fileA.pgp:decrypt (0:output file fileA.txt)
```

But this command cannot get the file content. how to do this?

Comment: What OS are you using? Add a tag. Also, what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this command:

```
pgp --decrypt fileA.pgp --passphrase 'pp123' --eyes-only --output std.txt --output-file err.txt
```